# Getting error while executing an exe file. "Reason: The System can't find the file specified"

Tags: exe, iexpress

I have converted the `test.bat` file to `test.exe` using `iexpress`tool in windows.When i run the `test.exe` file. I am getting error saying

```
Error Creating process<command.com /c
c:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Local\Temp\4\IXP000.TMP\test.bat>.
Reason:The system cannot find the file specified
```

When i run `test.bat` it is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is while generating exe using iexpress.

In Iexpress Wizard

goto - Install Program To Launch page

at [Install Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJi8M.png) tab - type as `cmd /c "test.bat"` instead of just selecting `test.bat` from drop down